# Passing 2 values from two different dropdownlists in C# (ASP.NET Core MVC) - not sure

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc

I am stuck on this situation, the thing is that i need to pass 2 values because i need those parameters in order to execute a stored procedure. Take a look, i select one value from **DROPDOWNLIST #1** and another value from **DROPDOWNLIST #2**

[image]

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="email1" asp-items="ViewBag.Email1"></select>
            </div>
            <h4>Email del reemplazante:</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="email2" asp-items="ViewBag.Email2"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

After clicking on SUBMIT button the create POST method on Controller file is called. I wrote this code but it does not look good to me, it does not throw any error message but i am not sending anything at all through the ExecuteProcedure method.

```
   public ActionResult Create(string email1,string email2, [Bind] Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    dbContext.ExecuteProcedure(person);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(dbContext);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

I guess this part of code is not good at all but dont really understand how to pass those 2 values from the HTML block to the Create from Controller file

Person model:
My Person Model:

```
public class Person{
public string PERSON1{get; set;}
public string PERSON2{get; set;}

}
```

My ExecuteProcedure method in detail:

```
  public void ExecuteProcedure(Person person)
        {
            using SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_CreateNewEmail", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PERSON1", person.PERSON1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PERSON2", person.PERSON2);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of email1 and email2 parameter use one model

```
public class Person{
public string PERSON1{get; set;}
public string PERSON2{get; set;}
public string email1{get;set;}
public string email2{get;set;}
}
```

In your controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    dbContext.ExecuteProcedure(person);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(dbContext);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey pal, thank you for replying. Gonna check that out!

Comment: Pal, i think it is working now but, can i ask you something?: What is it function doing?   ViewData["Email1"] = new SelectList(dbContext.GetEmailList().ToList(), "Email", "Email")

Comment: hope this one will help you https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists#creating-a-selectlist

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<select asp-for="Person1" asp-items="ViewBag.Email1"></select>
<select asp-for="Person2" asp-items="ViewBag.Email2"></select>
```